# Display avatar during chatting through XMPP

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I was able to display avatar through XMPP in the imageview.

But when I deleted the application and relaunched it since then I'm not getting the imagedata through method

```
 - (NSData *)photoDataForJID:(XMPPJID *)jid
```

Comment: This looks to me more an iOS question that an ejabberd question.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  What XMPP library are you using on iOS?  Can you see the avatar data leaving your XMPP server?

Comment: It's now solved. Actually i was getting data nil, in the response. And yeah i am using XMPP library on iOS.

Comment: Can you post the answer so that someone having a similar question will benefit from it?

Comment: Yeah of course. But there was no problem in the code. I didn't change anything in the code. Actually when i changed the avtar , so for some sake of time , the data for the avatar was nil . And so i was not getting data. And after refreshing after sometime , i got the photoData for avatar.